# how to set the template url in angular 2

Tags: angular, components, angular-components

I created a new angular app using `@angular/cli`. in that app template already have `app component`. inside that app component I want to use another `component` called `user`. so inside `@Component` there is a `property` called `templateUrl` and also some says to use only the `template`. so which one should I use and which is the best. currently I'm trying to use `templateUrl` with this.

think this is my `app.component.ts`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
```

and this is my `user.component.ts`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.css']
})
```

so how can I use my `user` component with `app component`. I tried by giving `relative paths` but it didn't work and gave `absolute path` didn't work that too. I'm confused. hope your help with this.

Comment: If you want to use the user component inside app component, then use `<app-user></app-user>` inside the template of app.

Comment: so what `templateUrl` for

Comment: Many times it is better to have a separate file for template so that it is easier to edit and maintain... U use templateUrl to provide link of file... If you want to add inline html, then use template

Answer (score 4):

Name `selector` in your `user.component.ts` file and use it in the `template` in the `app.component.ts` file. Then you can use both components.

user.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html', 
})
```

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template:`<app-user></app-user>`,
})
```

If you are creating files manually remember to add `UserComponent` in `declarations` of `app.module.ts` file.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UserComponent
  ],
```

Comment: with template property you need to add the html components in the .ts file, but in templateUrl  you can provide the link for the html file where you can keep a separate file for html components.

Answer (score 0):

> use my user component with app component.
>   If you want to use user component with app component, then

- add the user component inside the template of app 
  So your app.template. html will contain
  `<app-user></app-user>`
- Add the user component inside app.module

@NgModule({
...
declarations: [ AppComponent, UserComponent ]
...
})

You can learn more about multiple components [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt3.html)

Comment: I want to use it as `templateUrl`

Comment: `I wan't` -> you dont want to use templateurl? Or you want to use template url?

Comment: sorry my bad. typing mistake

Answer (score 0):

nothing to do with `template url`, just use the selector inside my `app component` like below.

inside my `app.component.html` we should use the `user` component `selector` name like below.

```
<div class="row">
    <app-user></app-user>
</div>
```

this will show the `user component` content inside the `app component`